# Не отображаются выбранные дочерние элементы

Tags: массивы, reactjs, typescript

Необходима помощь в отображении данных на странице, заранее, благодарен за помощь.

Есть массив accounts, который в себе содержит массив handbooks, который в себе содержить массив items, items в свою очередь может содержать массив childrens.

Что items, что childrens представляют собой массив объектов { id: number, name: string }

Также есть ещё один массив accounts, в массиве accounts, есть массив handbook_item_ids, которые хранит в себе айдишники тех значений, которые я когда-то выбрал, либо из items, либо из childrens первого массива accounts

Мне необходимо вернуть массив объектов items или childrens, которые содержат айдишники handbooks_item_ids          .

Что я для этого сделал, создал переменную analyticName, которая будет в себе хранить массив объектов.

Далее, создал метод, в который я в качестве параметров передаю (1. айдишник account, 2. айдишник handbook и 3. массив handbook_item_ids)

В самом методе, я перебираю первый accounts, проверяю, если он содержит айди, что я передал в параметрах, перебираю массив handbooks, если он содержит айди, что я передал в параметрах, то в ранее созданную переменную записываю отфильтрованный массив items.

Тут начинается самое интересное.

если items не содержит childrens, то проверяю, содержит ли handbook_items_ids, айдишники items и возвращаю. Этот кейс у меня отрабатывает корректно.

если items содержит childrens, то перебираю childrens, проверяю, содержит ли handbook_item_ids. айдишники items и возвращаю. Этот кейс не отрабатывает так как мне надо. Я получаю массив объектов, но как только заканчивается область видимости перебираемого childrens, у меня возвращается пустой массив.

```
    let analyticName: any[] = [];

    const getAccountAnalyticName = (accountId: number, handbookId: number, handbookItemIds: number[] | null) => {
        clientAccounts?.forEach(client => {
            if (client.id === accountId) {
                client.handbooks.forEach(handbook => {
                    if (handbook.id === handbookId) {
                        analyticName = handbook.items.filter(handbookItem => {
                            if (handbookItem.childrens) {
                                analyticName = handbookItem.childrens.filter(child => {
                                    return handbookItemIds?.includes(child.id)
                                })
                            } else {
                                return handbookItemIds?.includes(handbookItem.id)
                            }
                        })
                        return analyticName;
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        return analyticName.map(ch => ch.name)
    }
```

[image: первый массив accounts]

[image: второй массив accounts содержащий handbook_item_ids]

[image: метод getAccountAnalyticName]

[image: пример корректного возвращения массива объектов, не содержащих children]

[image: пример некорректного возвращения массива объектов, содержащего children]

Comment: добавь пример входных данных, пример что ты хочешь получить и что получаешь сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

Решил следующий образом. Вместо возвращения handbookItemIds?.includes(child.id), сделал условием

```
    const getAccountAnalyticName = (accountId: number, handbookId: number, handbookItemIds: number[] | null) => {
        let analyticName: any[] = [];

        clientAccounts?.forEach(client => {
            if (client.id === accountId) {
                client.handbooks.forEach(handbook => {
                    if (handbook.id === handbookId) {
                        handbook.items.forEach(handbookItem => {
                            if (handbookItem.childrens) {
                                handbookItem.childrens.forEach(child => {
                                    if (handbookItemIds?.includes(child.id)) {
                                        analyticName.push(child);
                                    }
                                })
                            } else {
                                if (handbookItemIds?.includes(handbookItem.id)) {
                                    analyticName.push(handbookItem)
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })

        return analyticName.map(ch => ch.name)
    }
```